# Flash 11.3.x + Firefox (protected mode) - Failed to connect to RTMPS stream

Tags: flash, firefox, streaming, wowza, rtmps

Opening a netconnection to an RTMPS stream fails without any notice (netstatus or error). This happens for Flash Player 11.3.x with the new protected mode for Firefox (only with the release Flash Player versions, only on Windows).

On our wowza media server (version 3.1.1), we can see the SSL handshake failing.

Has anyone a solution or workaround for that problem? Or had the same problem and can share how you solved it?

(There are also already posts in the Adobe forum about that problem but no responses, e.g. http://forums.adobe.com/message/4576128?tstart=0))

Thanks!

Comment: It turned out, setting the proxyType of the netConnection to "best" created the problem. According to the documentation, when setting it to "best" the player tries to create a native SSL connection. It seems that fails with the new protected mode (and also on the new Mac OSX 10.8 with every browser). Setting the proxyType to "none" (the default), solves the problem.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the default value of `proxyType`, `'none'`, will make your connections RTMPTS, which can be slow and cause additional server load.